Create a simple mesh using NetGen
I am trying to manually create a mesh using NetGen, but I get an access violation exception stepping into Ng_GenerateVolumeMesh. This is the C++ code that I using:
namespace nglib {
#include <nglib.h>
}

int main() {
    using namespace nglib;

    // NetGen initialization
    Ng_Init();

    // Creating Ng_Mesh object
    Ng_Mesh* mesh = Ng_NewMesh();

    // Adding vertices to the mesh
    double v0[] = { 0, 0, 0 };
    double v1[] = { 1, 0, 0 };
    double v2[] = { 1, 1, 0 };
    double v3[] = { 0, 1, 0 };
    double v00[] = { 0, 0, 1 };
    double v10[] = { 1, 0, 1 };
    double v20[] = { 1, 1, 1 };
    double v30[] = { 0, 1, 1 };
    Ng_AddPoint(mesh, v0);
    Ng_AddPoint(mesh, v1);
    Ng_AddPoint(mesh, v2);
    Ng_AddPoint(mesh, v3);
    Ng_AddPoint(mesh, v00);
    Ng_AddPoint(mesh, v10);
    Ng_AddPoint(mesh, v20);
    Ng_AddPoint(mesh, v30);

    // Creating faces (triangles)
    int trig0[] = { 0, 3, 2};
    Ng_AddSurfaceElement(mesh, NG_TRIG, trig0);
    int trig1[] = { 0, 2, 1 };
    Ng_AddSurfaceElement(mesh, NG_TRIG, trig1);

    int trig2[] = { 0, 5, 4 };
    Ng_AddSurfaceElement(mesh, NG_TRIG, trig2);
    int trig3[] = { 0, 1, 5 };
    Ng_AddSurfaceElement(mesh, NG_TRIG, trig3);

    int trig4[] = { 1, 6, 5 };
    Ng_AddSurfaceElement(mesh, NG_TRIG, trig4);
    int trig5[] = { 1, 2, 6 };
    Ng_AddSurfaceElement(mesh, NG_TRIG, trig5);

    int trig6[] = { 2, 7, 6 };
    Ng_AddSurfaceElement(mesh, NG_TRIG, trig6);
    int trig7[] = { 2, 3, 7 };
    Ng_AddSurfaceElement(mesh, NG_TRIG, trig7);

    int trig8[] = { 3, 4, 7 };
    Ng_AddSurfaceElement(mesh, NG_TRIG, trig8);
    int trig9[] = { 3, 0, 4 };
    Ng_AddSurfaceElement(mesh, NG_TRIG, trig9);

    int trig10[] = { 4, 6, 7 };
    Ng_AddSurfaceElement(mesh, NG_TRIG, trig10);
    int trig11[] = { 4, 5, 6 };
    Ng_AddSurfaceElement(mesh, NG_TRIG, trig11);

    // Meshing options
    Ng_Meshing_Parameters mp;
    mp.maxh = .1;
    mp.second_order = 1;

    // Mesh generation
    Ng_Result res = Ng_GenerateVolumeMesh(mesh, &mp);

    // Shutdown
    Ng_Exit();

    return 0;
}

I have built the library from sources. https://github.com/NGSolve/ngsolve.git commit date Wed Apr 3 09:16:29 2024.
The exception says (sorry it's in Italian):
Eccezione generata in corrispondenza di 0x00007FFE894DEB45 (nglib.dll) in TestNetGen.exe: 0xC0000005: violazione di accesso durante la lettura del percorso 0x000001803583E410.
Stack trace:
[Frame inline] nglib.dll!netgen::TABLE<int,1>::operator[](int) Riga 252 C++
nglib.dll!netgen::Mesh::CalcSurfacesOfNode() Riga 2250  C++
nglib.dll!netgen::Mesh::Compress() Riga 4172    C++
nglib.dll!netgen::MeshVolume(const netgen::MeshingParameters & mp, netgen::Mesh & mesh3d) Riga 590  C++
nglib.dll!nglib::Ng_GenerateVolumeMesh(void * * mesh, nglib::Ng_Meshing_Parameters * mp) Riga 373   C++
TestNetGen.exe!main() Riga 73   C++

Edit:
I found this question that seems to be the same problem.

What are the results of your debugging? You should be able to see what causes it if you manually step the code.

At a first glance, there's an issue with the surface nodes array (most likely, not initialized or filled in properly). This is just reading the source code. To properly determine the issue or actual cause, you need to debug it and check vs tutorials or reference code to see whether you skipped any steps in the mesh creation or its setup. Unfortunately, I don't have NG and am unfamiliar with setting it up, so you'll need to check and tell us what you find so we can help further (unless someone that worked with it more in-depth can jump in).

Seeing the source, the problem is determining the surface nodes. When accessing if (!surfacesonnode[pi].Contains(si)) it returns a corrupt object (that's usually the 0xC0000005), pi being not 3.14, but actually a point index when traversing the surface elements in sel. While pi can possibly be "correct garbage" and advance in the code (you need to confirm that) I doubt it, there might be a higher chance that surfacesonnode is the culprit, defined as TABLE<int,PointIndex::BASE> surfacesonnode(GetNP());. Judging by the error, it's that array in operator [] as in the callstack.

This can mean a lot of things, but in general, either it's an out-of-bounds access (for example accessing element 5 out of a 3 item array) or accessing a correctly indexed item, but having garbage data stored in it (for example a destroyed object of freed memory or any structure that went out of scope and is just dangling to whatever it can). That's as much clairvoyance as I can do without more info. But it should be enough for you to dig deeper.

My example was correct but the index of the vertices has to start from one, not from zero.
A complete revised example follows:
namespace nglib {
#include <nglib.h>
}

int main() {
    using namespace nglib;

    // NetGen initialization
    Ng_Init();

    // Creating Ng_Mesh object
    Ng_Mesh* mesh = Ng_NewMesh();

    // Adding vertices to the mesh
    double v0[] = { 0, 0, 0 };
    double v1[] = { 1, 0, 0 };
    double v2[] = { 1, 1, 0 };
    double v3[] = { 0, 1, 0 };
    double v00[] = { 0, 0, 1 };
    double v10[] = { 1, 0, 1 };
    double v20[] = { 1, 1, 1 };
    double v30[] = { 0, 1, 1 };
    Ng_AddPoint(mesh, v0);
    Ng_AddPoint(mesh, v1);
    Ng_AddPoint(mesh, v2);
    Ng_AddPoint(mesh, v3);
    Ng_AddPoint(mesh, v00);
    Ng_AddPoint(mesh, v10);
    Ng_AddPoint(mesh, v20);
    Ng_AddPoint(mesh, v30);

    // Creating faces (triangles)
    int trig0[] = { 1, 4, 3 };
    Ng_AddSurfaceElement(mesh, NG_TRIG, trig0);
    int trig1[] = { 1, 3, 2 };
    Ng_AddSurfaceElement(mesh, NG_TRIG, trig1);

    int trig2[] = { 1, 6, 5 };
    Ng_AddSurfaceElement(mesh, NG_TRIG, trig2);
    int trig3[] = { 1, 2, 6 };
    Ng_AddSurfaceElement(mesh, NG_TRIG, trig3);

    int trig4[] = { 2, 7, 6 };
    Ng_AddSurfaceElement(mesh, NG_TRIG, trig4);
    int trig5[] = { 2, 3, 7 };
    Ng_AddSurfaceElement(mesh, NG_TRIG, trig5);

    int trig6[] = { 3, 8, 7 };
    Ng_AddSurfaceElement(mesh, NG_TRIG, trig6);
    int trig7[] = { 3, 4, 8 };
    Ng_AddSurfaceElement(mesh, NG_TRIG, trig7);

    int trig8[] = { 4, 5, 8 };
    Ng_AddSurfaceElement(mesh, NG_TRIG, trig8);
    int trig9[] = { 4, 1, 5 };
    Ng_AddSurfaceElement(mesh, NG_TRIG, trig9);

    int trig10[] = { 5, 7, 8 };
    Ng_AddSurfaceElement(mesh, NG_TRIG, trig10);
    int trig11[] = { 5, 6, 7 };
    Ng_AddSurfaceElement(mesh, NG_TRIG, trig11);

    // Set default mesh parameters
    Ng_Meshing_Parameters mp = Ng_Meshing_Parameters();

    // Mesh generation
    Ng_Result res = Ng_GenerateVolumeMesh(mesh, &mp);

    // Free memory
    Ng_DeleteMesh(mesh);

    // Shutdown di NetGen
    Ng_Exit();

    return 0;
}

In other words I have changed the triangle definition instructions from:
    int trig0[] = { 0, 3, 2};
    int trig1[] = { 0, 2, 1 };
    int trig2[] = { 0, 5, 4 };
    int trig3[] = { 0, 1, 5 };
    int trig4[] = { 1, 6, 5 };
    int trig5[] = { 1, 2, 6 };
    int trig6[] = { 2, 7, 6 };
    int trig7[] = { 2, 3, 7 };
    int trig8[] = { 3, 4, 7 };
    int trig9[] = { 3, 0, 4 };
    int trig10[] = { 4, 6, 7 };
    int trig11[] = { 4, 5, 6 };

to:
    int trig0[] = { 1, 4, 3 };
    int trig1[] = { 1, 3, 2 };
    int trig2[] = { 1, 6, 5 };
    int trig3[] = { 1, 2, 6 };
    int trig4[] = { 2, 7, 6 };
    int trig5[] = { 2, 3, 7 };
    int trig6[] = { 3, 8, 7 };
    int trig7[] = { 3, 4, 8 };
    int trig8[] = { 4, 5, 8 };
    int trig9[] = { 4, 1, 5 };
    int trig10[] = { 5, 7, 8 };
    int trig11[] = { 5, 6, 7 };


So what did you change exactly? In case others have the same problem as you, so they can quickly identify the cause if they are beginners in NetGen.

Please [edit] and show what you have changed instead of only describing it . You'll get my upvote. It's absolutely unclear from your description.

@Jabberwocky Should be clear now.
